# Parcel: JSON5: invalid character '\'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, parceljs, json5

On trying to build a react app using tailwind and postcss, it throws me this error.

```
 /mnt/c/Users/Shaleen/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Courses/Frontend Masters/Intro to React V6/adopt-me/src/style.css:undefined:undefined: JSON5: invalid character '\"' at 5:9
    at syntaxError (/mnt/c/Users/Shaleen/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Courses/Frontend Masters/Intro to React V6/adopt-me/node_modules/json5/lib/parse.js:1:12963)
    at invalidChar (/mnt/c/Users/Shaleen/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Courses/Frontend Masters/Intro to React V6/adopt-me/node_modules/json5/lib/parse.js:1:12177)
    at Object.afterPropertyValue (/mnt/c/Users/Shaleen/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Courses/Frontend Masters/Intro to React V6/adopt-me/node_modules/json5/lib/parse.js:1:8133)
    at Object._default [as default] (/mnt/c/Users/Shaleen/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Courses/Frontend Masters/Intro to React V6/adopt-me/node_modules/json5/lib/parse.js:1:2255)
    at lex (/mnt/c/Users/Shaleen/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Courses/Frontend Masters/Intro to React V6/adopt-me/node_modules/json5/lib/parse.js:1:1680)
    at parse (/mnt/c/Users/Shaleen/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Courses/Frontend Masters/Intro to React V6/adopt-me/node_modules/json5/lib/parse.js:1:992)
    at Object.load (/mnt/c/Users/Shaleen/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Courses/Frontend Masters/Intro to React V6/adopt-me/node_modules/parcel/src/utils/config.js:45:30)
    at async getConfig (/mnt/c/Users/Shaleen/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Courses/Frontend Masters/Intro to React V6/adopt-me/node_modules/parcel/src/transforms/postcss.js:25:16)
    at async module.exports (/mnt/c/Users/Shaleen/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Courses/Frontend Masters/Intro to React V6/adopt-me/node_modules/parcel/src/transforms/postcss.js:11:16)
    at async CSSAsset.transform (/mnt/c/Users/Shaleen/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Courses/Frontend Masters/Intro to React V6/adopt-me/node_modules/parcel/src/assets/CSSAsset.js:133:5)
```

my style.css is

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I have not been able to debug this issue, I tried using different node versions but I can not change any package versions since this a course I'm doing and I have to follow their package.json, any idea what I can do here?

Here's my [repository link](https://github.com/ShaleenAg/Intermediate-React-V6) and the [issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/6728) I have created on parcel github page.

Comment: this can happen occasionally with hidden line feeds, but its rare nowadays. Still could be worth checking, you can do it with Notepad++, open it up in there then go to to Edit > EOL Conversion

Comment: I am using WSL 2, how should I go about doing it ?

Comment: tried dos2unix to convert it but it didn't work

Comment: Whats the reason for using a linux env ?